# How do I change the colour of a div with one button using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to Javascript so feel free to point out anything I am doing wrong. I am trying to change the colour of a div everytime a button is clicked. This is my code so far:

```
function setBgColour(){
        if (.backgroundColor == '#ff0000'){
            document.getElementsByClassName("light")[0].style.backgroundColor = '#ffff00';
        } else if (.backgroundColor == '#ffff00'){
            document.getElementsByClassName("light")[0].style.backgroundColor = '#00ff00'
        } else if (.backgroundColor == '#00ff00'){
            document.getElementsByClassName("light")[0].style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000'
        }
    }

    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', setBgColour);
    };
```

Comment: would it be better to store the colours within an array? and cycle through them

Comment: remove the dots in the if.

Comment: Unless there's a reason not to do so. I'd suggest you start using jQuery. It makes javascript quite a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your condition statements. You're doing:

```
if (.backgroundColor == '#ff0000')
```

What's the element you're looking into, to get the `backgroundColor` property?

You should do something like:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var current = '#ff0000';

  function setBgColour() {
    var light = document.getElementsByClassName("light")[0];
    if (current == '#ff0000') {
      current = '#ffff00';
    } else if (current == '#ffff00') {
      current = '#00ff00';
    } else if (current == '#00ff00') {
      current = '#ff0000';
    }

    light.style.backgroundColor = current;
  }

  document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', setBgColour);
  setBgColour();
};
```

```css
.light {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="light"></div>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

Comment: ah, thank you very much. I understand where I went wrong now